# Avoid redundant dereferencing in iOS

Tags: ios, struct

Suppose I want to change size of an `uiView: UIView` to w,h. I can do it like that:

```
    uiView.frame.size.width = w
    uiView.frame.size.height = h
```

In another system I can avoid replication of dereferencing (which means waste of both size and performance) by keeping a reference in a variable (using Swift syntax):

```
    let ref = uiView.frame.size
    ref.width = v
    ref.height = h
```

This however doesn't work in iOS, where CGSize is a structure and therefore is copied when assigned to another value.

Is there a way to avoid redundant dereferencing (something like `with(uiView.frame.size){...}` available in some languages)

Comment: Short answer - no, there is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is even simpler:

```
   uiView.frame.size = CGSize(width: w, height: h)
```

As I understand it, RHS is a temporary value released as soon as the content has been copied to frame structure.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to do it exactly because the frame is a value-copied structure. You could set the frame directly as Reiner Melian suggests, but to me that seems even longer and uses dereferencing at least the same amount of time as your approach.

There is a way how to make it simpler this using extensions, but behind the scenes it will again be using dereferencing:

```
extension UIView {
    var width: CGFloat {
        get {
            return self.frame.size.width
        }
        set {
            self.frame.size.width = newValue
        }
    }
    var height: CGFloat {
        get {
            return self.frame.size.height
        }
        set {
            self.frame.size.height = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

And then you could use:

```
uiView.width = w
uiView.height = h
```

on any `UIView` instance.

Comment: Performance it doesn't save for sure, but app size maybe :)  I wonder if the compiler is intelligent enough to figure that out and optimise.

Comment: Wait for a while and mark that as an answer for nothing better :)